# why are my iPhone4 videos different in size?

Tags: video, disk-format

Some videos I take are square and 640 x 480, while others are 1920 x 1080, data rate changes with size as well, so quality is much better on the larger size - seems to be random - how do i set the size so all vids record the same? preferably the larger size.

Comment: Any chance that you are editing the videos and that the low quality ones were taken vertical?

Comment: How do you take the different videos? All with the standard camera app and the lens on the back? Or are you using a video app from the app store?

Comment: Did you shoot them yourself or obtained them elsewhere? E.g. WhatsApp?

Answer (score 1):

Recording videos with Instagram will save them in the lower resolution. To record at native resolution, use the Camera app.